# Unable to resolve service for type on interface when activating controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I've created a bogus service to mimic data being retrieved back from an api, but when I make a Get request to my end point i am greeted with the following error:

> Unable to resolve service for type 'project.API.Features.Reservation.Services.IReservationDetailService' while attempting to activate 'project.API.Server.Controllers.BookingDetailController'."

my code is as follows:

```
public class BookingDetailController : BaseController
{
    private readonly IReservationDetailService _ReservationDetailService;

    public BookingDetailController(IReservationDetailService ReservationDetailService)
    {
        _ReservationDetailService = ReservationDetailService;
    }

    public async Task<ActionResult> Get([Description("The details for a reservation")] string hotelCode)
    {
        var result =  _ReservationDetailService.GetReservationDetail(hotelCode);
        return Ok(result);
    }
}
```

```
public class ReservationDetailsBogusService : IReservationDetailApi
{

    public async Task<BaseDataResultApiModel<List<ReservationDetails>>> GetReservationDetail(string hotelCode)
    {
        return new BaseDataResultApiModel<List<ReservationDetails>>{Data = GetFakeReservation()};
    }

    private List<ReservationDetails> GetFakeReservation()
    {
        return new List<ReservationDetails>
        {
            new ReservationDetails
            {
                HotelName = "Amsterdam",
                BookingReference = 1234,
                StartDate = new DateTime(2020, 02, 10),
                EndDate = new DateTime(2020, 02, 14),
                NumberOfUnits = 1,
                TotalPrice = 897,
                HotelCode = "ghfhshth323",
                Country = "The Netherlands",
                Address = "2 Test road",
                City = "Amsterdam",
                RoomFacilities = "Private Bathroom",
                Guests = 2,
                ImageIUrl = "http://via.placeholder.com/640x360",
                TelephoneNo = 0123456789,
                ExtraServicesDay = "Cleaning",
                HotelEmail = "amscity@blah.com"
            }
        };
    }
}
```

```
public interface IReservationDetailApi
{
    Task<BaseDataResultApiModel<List<ReservationDetails>>> GetReservationDetail(string hotelCode);
}
```

```
public interface IReservationDetailService
{
    List<ReservationDetails> GetReservationDetail(string hotelCode);
}
```

```
public static class ServiceCollectionExtensions
{
    public static void GetReservationsFeature(this IServiceCollection serviceCollection, IConfiguration config)
    {
        config.ThrowIfNull(nameof(config));

        var iruSection = config.GetSection("IRU");
        var endpoints = iruSection.Get<EndpointsConfig>();

        serviceCollection.AddRefitClient<IReservationDetailApi>()
            .ConfigureHttpClient(client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(endpoints.DataEndpoint))
            .AddHttpMessageHandler<ReckonUHttpClientHandler>();

        serviceCollection.AddScoped<IReservationDetailApi, ReservationDetailsBogusService>();
    }
}
```

and yes i have added the necessary implementation to my startup.cs file

```
services.GetReservationsFeature(_configuration);
```

quite honestly stumped here, can someone please advise why IReservationDetailService is Unable to resolve service for type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `services.GetReservationsFeature(_configuration);` extension method you are not registering the `IReservationDetailService` but the `IReservationDetailApi`.

Also your service class implements the `IReservationDetailApi` interface.

When DI attempts to create the `BookingDetailController` it is looking in the service collection for the `IReservationDetailService` but it doesn't know anything about it - hence the exception you are seeing.

You can do one of two things:

1. Change the constructor to accept `IReservationDetailApi` and change the variables to match:

```
public class BookingDetailController : BaseController
{
    private readonly IReservationDetailApi _reservationDetailApi;

    public BookingDetailController(IReservationDetailApi reservationDetailApi)
    {
        _reservationDetailApi = reservationDetailApi;
    }

    public async Task<ActionResult> Get([Description("The details for a reservation")] string hotelCode)
    {
        var result = _reservationDetailApi.GetReservationDetail(hotelCode);
        return Ok(result);
    }
}
```

2. Change your service to implement the `IReservationDetailService` interface and change the `GetReservationsFeature` extension method to register the `IReservationDetailService` interface:

```
public class ReservationDetailsBogusService : IReservationDetailService
{
    public async Task<List<ReservationDetails>> GetReservationDetail(string hotelCode)
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

```
public static class ServiceCollectionExtensions
{
    public static void GetReservationsFeature(this IServiceCollection serviceCollection, IConfiguration config)
    {
        // other code removed but stays the same
        ...

        serviceCollection.AddScoped<IReservationDetailService, ReservationDetailsBogusService>();
    }
}
```